# To DOHC or not to DOHC

Tags: engine, nissan, altima, compatibility

I'm looking at replacement engines for my 2003 Nissan Altima 2.5 L 4-cylinder and I see one that mentions having the DOHC.

I'm wondering does that matter or not because I see others that do not have the DOHC.

Comment: Welcome to the site. It would help if you could add more information that illustrates the difference between the two options. Do you have engine codes or pictures? And is your Altima's engine DOHC?

Comment: Thats what I dont know. If the engine doesnt come with the DOHC would it still work or no. Would the VIN # help?

Comment: Is the engine that is present in your Altima DOHC or non-DOHC?

Comment: Doesnt have a engine. I bought it wothout one

Comment: Im wondering which one to buy. How can I know my 03 Altima is fit for DOHC?

Comment: When you run the VIN through a [decoder](https://www.vindecoderz.com/EN/Nissan/ALTIMA), what engine type do you get?

Comment: All I know is that it is a 2.5 4 cylinder. Never ran VIN through decoder

Comment: Could you try getting that information?

Comment: What do you think DOHC stands for - question for OP only...

Comment: To the OP: [Maybe this answer will help you understand the difference between a DOHC and SOHC](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/8137/4152).

Answer (score 1):

All Nissan Altima from that generation have a [DOHC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nissan_QR_engine) engine, so there is no difference.